# Safari not accepting Cookies while FF and IE does

Tags: cookies, safari

i have a problem with the safari browser and our set-cookie.
Safari is ignoring our set-cookies completely while FF and IE accept and send the cookies.
The Cookie setting page is not a redirection, direct HTTP 200 with set-cookie.

Is there a special character or malformed set-cookie that causes Safari to ignore the cookies completely?

The following Cookies are sent:

**CURL output:**

Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=rdmpn1b4eckozzjns0voon33; path=/

Set-Cookie: SHOPPERID=jZlotLr6HESiqoB/3F0brg==; expires=Wed, 28-Jul-2060 01:09:04 GMT;path=/

Set-Cookie: FVISIT=2010?N7??28??; expires=Wed, 28-Jul-2060 01:09:04 GMT; path=/

Set-Cookie: STOCKMCD=Direct=2010/07/28 10:09:04; expires=Tue, 26-Oct-2010 01:09:04 GMT; path=/

**Safari Developer Tools:**

Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=xqf3eui1r2fce4e30ogh2145; path=/, SHOPPERID=C/lG3XGVPEa7QgGcsqt3yg==; expires=Wed, 28-Jul-2060 01:15:26 GMT; path=/, FVISIT=2010N728ú; expires=Wed, 28-Jul-2060 01:15:26 GMT; path=/, STOCKMCD=Direct=2010/07/28 10:15:26; expires=Tue, 26-Oct-2010 01:15:26 GMT; path=/

Answer (score 5):

With default privacy settings Safari rejects cookies from domains other than user visited. For example, if page from example.com contains resources from example.net, example.net is not allowed to set cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers to [HTTP headers encoding/decoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324470/http-headers-encoding-decoding-in-java).  It looks as if the `Set-Cookie` header being sent has an character without a valid encoding.  It seems that IE and Firefox are less strict than Safari.