# How to upload images using wordpress REST api in python?

Tags: python, wordpress, rest, python-requests, wp-api

I think I've got this 90% working, but it ends up 'uploading' a blank transparent image. I get a 201 response after the upload. I think that's probably a proxy for when WP finds a missing image. I'm unsure if i'm passing the image incorrectly (ie it doesn't leave my computer) or if I'm not tagging it properly to WP's liking.

```
from base64 import b64encode
import json
import requests

def imgUploadREST(imgPath):
    url = 'https://www.XXXXXXXXXX.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    auth = b64encode('{}:{}'.format('USERNAME','PASS'))
    payload = {
        'type': 'image/jpeg',  # mimetype
        'title': 'title',
        "Content":"content",
        "excerpt":"Excerpt",
    }
    headers = {
        'post_content':'post_content',
        'Content':'content',
        'Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=image_20170510.jpg',
        'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(auth),
    }
    with open(imgPath, "rb") as image_file:
        files = {'field_name': image_file}
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, data=payload) 
        print r
        response = json.loads(r.content)
        print response
    return response
```

I've seen a fair number of answers in php or node.js, but I'm having trouble understanding the syntax in python. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I've figured it out.

Answer (score 21):

I've figured it out!

With this function I'm able to upload images via the WP REST api to my site ([Photo Gear Hunter.](https://www.photogearhunter.com/)) The function returns the ID of the image. You can then pass that id to a new post call and make it the featured image, or do whatever you wish with it.

```
def restImgUL(imgPath):
    url='http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    data = open(imgPath, 'rb').read()
    fileName = os.path.basename(imgPath)
    res = requests.post(url='http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                        data=data,
                        headers={ 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg','Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=%s'% fileName},
                        auth=('authname', 'authpass'))
    # pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4) ## print it pretty. 
    # pp.pprint(res.json()) #this is nice when you need it
    newDict=res.json()
    newID= newDict.get('id')
    link = newDict.get('guid').get("rendered")
    print newID, link
    return (newID, link)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. This is really nice. It worked for me also.

Comment: Is there an alternative configuration for using cookie-based authentication (WP's default)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. My config was created long before I even thought about using a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

To specify additional fields supported by the api such as alt text, description ect:

```
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import os
fileName = os.path.basename(imgPath)
multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        # a file upload field
        'file': (fileName, open(imgPath, 'rb'), 'image/jpg'),
        # plain text fields
        'alt_text': 'alt test',
        'caption': 'caption test',
        'description': 'description test'
    }
)

response = requests.post('http://example/wp-json/wp/v2/media', data=multipart_data,
                         headers={'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type},
                         auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 1):

An improved version to **handle non-ASCII in the filename** (Greek, Cyrillic etc. letters for example). What it does is convert all non-ASCII characters to a UTF-8 escape sequence.
(Original code from [@my Year Of Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7997301/my-year-of-code))

```
def uploadImage(filePath):
    data = open(filePath, 'rb').read()
    
    fileName = os.path.basename(filePath)
    
    espSequence = bytes(fileName, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")  
    # Convert all non ASCII characters to UTF-8 escape sequence

    res = requests.post(url='http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                        data=data,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                                 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=%s' % espSequence,
                                 },
                        auth=('authname', 'authpass'))
    newDict=res.json()
    newID= newDict.get('id')
    link = newDict.get('guid').get("rendered")
    print newID, link
    return (newID, link)
```

From my understading **[a POST HEADER can only contain ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251951/14038782)**

Answer (score 0):

thanks to `@my Year Of Code`.

my final working code:

```py
import 
HOST = "https://www.crifan.com"
API_MEDIA = HOST + "/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
JWT_TOKEN = "eyJxxxxxxxxjLYB4"

    imgMime = gImageSuffixToMime[imgSuffix] # 'image/png'
    imgeFilename = "%s.%s" % (processedGuid, imgSuffix) # 'f6956c30ef0b475fa2b99c2f49622e35.png'
    authValue = "Bearer %s" % JWT_TOKEN
    curHeaders = {
        "Authorization": authValue,
        "Content-Type": imgMime,
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=%s' % imgeFilename,
    }
    # curHeaders={'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0xxxyyy.zzzB4', 'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=f6956c30ef0b475fa2b99c2f49622e35.png'}
    uploadImgUrl = API_MEDIA
    resp = requests.post(
        uploadImgUrl,
        # proxies=cfgProxies,
        headers=curHeaders,
        data=imgBytes,
    )
```

return `201` means `Created OK`

response json look like:

```
{
  "id": 70393,
  "date": "2020-03-07T18:43:47",
  "date_gmt": "2020-03-07T10:43:47",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": "https://www.crifan.com/files/pic/uploads/2020/03/f6956c30ef0b475fa2b99c2f49622e35.png",
    "raw": "https://www.crifan.com/files/pic/uploads/2020/03/f6956c30ef0b475fa2b99c2f49622e35.png"
  },
...
```

more details refer my (Chinese) post: [【已解决】用Python通过WordPress的REST API上传图片](http://www.crifan.com/use_python_upload_image_file_for_wordpress_rest_api)

Comment: Since the header is a dictionary and not a string, the syntax can be written much simpler

"Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=" + espSequence

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code for uploading image into WordPress from local image or from url. hope someone find it useful.

```
import requests, json, os, base64

def wp_upload_image(domain, user, app_pass, imgPath):
    # imgPath can be local image path or can be url
    url = 'https://'+ domain + '/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    filename = imgPath.split('/')[-1] if len(imgPath.split('/')[-1])>1 else imgPath.split('\\')[-1]
    extension = imgPath[imgPath.rfind('.')+1 : len(imgPath)]
    if imgPath.find('http') == -1:
        try: data = open(imgPath, 'rb').read()
        except:
            print('image local path not exits')
            return None
    else:
        rs = requests.get(imgPath)
        if rs.status_code == 200:
            data = rs.content
        else:
            print('url get request failed')
            return None
    headers = { "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename={filename}" , "Content-Type": str("image/" + extension)}
    rs = requests.post(url, auth=(user, app_pass), headers=headers, data=data)
    print(rs)
    return (rs.json()['source_url'], rs.json()['id'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import base64
import os

import requests

def rest_image_upload(image_path):
    message = '<user_name>' + ":" + '<application password>'
    message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
    base64_message = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')

    # print(base64_message)

    data = open(image_path, 'rb').read()
    file_name = os.path.basename(image_path)
    res = requests.post(url='https://<example.com>/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                    data=data,
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
                             'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name,
                             'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64_message})
    new_dict = res.json()
    new_id = new_dict.get('id')
    link = new_dict.get('guid').get("rendered")
    # print(new_id, link)
    return new_id, link
```

Comment: could be improved with explanations of your code