# I am not able to see 'create application password' section in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a script from [How to upload images using wordpress REST api in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915184/how-to-upload-images-using-wordpress-rest-api-in-python)

The only problem is that I am not able to see the the section where I can create application password. My only goal is to create a application password, I don't know what else to write but feel free to ask me anything anytime.

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbM1u.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the screenshot of WordPress admin you share, I found that you are using wordpress.com to host your website.

This is surely limited by wordpress.com

See [WordPress.com plans](https://wordpress.com/pricing/) to know, which plan includes what.

You can host WordPress at own hosting to get this access. WordPress source code can be downloaded from [WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/download/)