# Request headers must contain only ASCII characters while using c# http client?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to make a POST call by passing header but at some point of time I am getting an error as:

```
Request headers must contain only ASCII characters.
```

With stacktrace as:

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteStringAsync(String s)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteHeadersAsync(HttpHeaders headers, String cookiesFromContainer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

Here is my code:

```
public HttpWrapper(string endpoint, Func<IDictionary<string, string>> NewHeader)
{
    _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint);

    if (NewHeader != null)
    {
        var headers = NewHeader();
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to do something with `header.Value` to fix this issue? I was reading online so looks like I need to use Utf-8 here but not sure on how to do it properly?

**Update**

I got header value like this today and it threw same exception since `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` didn't do anything on it. Also I am not sure what is this character `<0x94>`? Any thoughts why it is happening?

Also I am not sure

[image]

Comment: "In order to use non ASCII characters in URI you need to escape them using the %hexcode syntax (see section 2 of RFC 2396)." from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251951/5386938

Comment: How do I do that @JustinEzequiel?

Comment: Here's [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34189188/5386938)

Comment: What about the accepted answer? Is that correct way as well? @JustinEzequiel

Comment: If the accepted answer works for you then good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to encode header values to HTML:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(header.Value));
```

Your string, Ergänzendes will be "`Erg&#228;nzendes`".

Comment: I tried like this already but it doesn't give me that value - `string str = "Ergänzendes";
            string val = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
            Console.WriteLine(val);` back. Is this the right expectation? It just prints this value `RXJnw6RuemVuZGVz`

Comment: So internally `httpclient` will convert this base64 encoded string `RXJnw6RuemVuZGVz` to the way it came back originally? Is my assumptions correct here?

Comment: Hmm, it's changing the original text. You can try to encode to HMTL your string. The answer is updated.

Comment: It then prints like this - `Erg&#228;nzendes`. I am not sure if that is the right way?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way. The browsers render the header text to "Ergänzendes ".

Comment: In my case I am calling a different service using `httpclient` by passing these headers so do you think this is the right way for the fix? They should be able to encode this back properly?

Comment: They can decode the data into "Ergänzendes " without any problem using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Erg&#228;nzendes"). You can't send non ASCII chars through headers thus, you have to decode to html.

Comment: Maybe other headers have the same problem?

Comment: yeah nvm I got that fixed. Sorry for late reply on that. I got one very weird problem now. For some reason today we saw a string coming as like I posted in my question and `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` didn't do anything on that and then later on my HttpClient threw exception with same `Request headers must contain only ASCII characters.` Any thoughts why it could be and how we can solve it?

Comment: It looks like it's a cancel character but not sure why `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` didn't do anything on it?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this may help in your specific scenario or others with a similar situation.
In my case, my header was containing **non ASCII** characters as one of the Headers values was generated by creating a *sha256 HMAC*. That was a requirement from the service I was trying to send my request.
So, what I had to do in order to **encode** those characters into ASCII was  just this:

```
//hashedSignature is the one containing NON ASCII charcters!
string MessageSignatureValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashedSignature); 
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(MessageSignaturField, MessageSignatureValue);
```

I have just included the importants pieces of code.

So, *System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString()* method did the trick!

Again, I hope it helps.

Comment: I see.  So what's the difference between accepted answer and your suggestion? Any thoughts?

Comment: You sure this is the right syntax - `string MessageSignatureValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashedSignature); `?

Comment: Honestly, I have never used **HttpUtility**. So, I haven't a concrete answer about that. But, from the documentation it states:  "Converts a string into an *HTML-encoded* string."
If that works for you there will be no difference, except the in the way I call the method it's telling that you want something **encoded** to ASCII explicitely. Maybe, it's more esay to understand the purpose. Just a thought.
Here you have the [link to the ASCIIEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getstring?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: This answer will convert non-recognised characters to '?' so the outputted header value or name, will have a '?' somewhere in the char sequence where the non-ascii char was detected. This might not be the answer some devs are looking for,.