# What's the text encoding used for header values on HTTP requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, encoding, ruby-1.8

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is a server for Java and .Net apps. I have a custom header I'm using to send some data, but when this data reaches the Ruby on Rails app, Rails reads the value as UTF-8 then says the value **is not** a valid UTF-8 string.

For instance, if I send **JÜRGENELITE-HP**  I get:

```
#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xdc52
: SELECT * FROM "replicas" WHERE ("replicas"."identification" = 'J?RGENELITE-HP') AND ("replicas".user_id = 121)  LIMIT 1>
```

The Java HTTP Client library clearly prints the data correctly in the console:

```
DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:268) - >> POST /ze/api/files.json HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:271) - >> X-Replica: JÜRGENELITE-HP
DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:271) - >> Authorization: Basic bWxpbmhhcmVzOjEyMzQ1Njc4

DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:271) - >> Content-Length: 0
DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:271) - >> Host: localhost:3000
DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:271) - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG [main] (DefaultClientConnection.java:271) - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)
```

But when it reaches Rails it breaks. What encoding does HTTP uses to encode header values?

Comment: You may be able to leverage [the solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361604/how-to-encode-utf8-filename-for-http-headers-python-django) to work around what you're trying to do.

Comment: [A handful of good answers here, too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324470/http-headers-encoding-decoding-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**US-ASCII**

If you look at section 2.2 of [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> 2.2 Basic Rules
>
> The following rules are used throughout this specification to
>   describe basic parsing constructs. The US-ASCII coded character set
>   is defined by ANSI X3.4-1986 [21].
>
> ```
>    OCTET          = <any 8-bit sequence of data>
>    CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
>    UPALPHA        = <any US-ASCII uppercase letter "A".."Z">
>    LOALPHA        = <any US-ASCII lowercase letter "a".."z">
>    ALPHA          = UPALPHA | LOALPHA
>    DIGIT          = <any US-ASCII digit "0".."9">
>    CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
>                     (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
>    CR             = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
>    LF             = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
>    SP             = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>
>    HT             = <US-ASCII HT, horizontal-tab (9)>
>    <">            = <US-ASCII double-quote mark (34)>
> ```

The remainder of the section has more specific information about headers and other elements of the protocol.

You have to jump around the spec quite a bit to find all of the right BNF definitions. Section 4.2 contains the definition for headers, though:

> ```
>    message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
>    field-name     = token
>    field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
>    field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
>                     and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
>                     of token, separators, and quoted-string>
> ```

`TEXT` is defined back in Section 2.2:

> ```
>    TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs,
>                     but including LWS>
> ```