# Sending UTF-8 values in HTTP headers results in Mojibake

Tags: java, http, servlets, utf-8, header

i want to send arabic data from servlet using `HTTPServletResponse` to client

i am trying this

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Info", arabicWord);
```

and i receive the word like this

```
String arabicWord = response.getHeader("Info");
```

in client(receiving) also tried this

```
byte[]d = response.getHeader("Info").getBytes("UTF-8");
arabicWord = new String(d);
```

but seems like there is no unicode because i receive strange english words,so please how can i send and receive arabic utf8 words?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

HTTP headers doesn't support UTF-8. They officially support ISO-8859-1 only. See also [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) [section 2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html):

> Words of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO- 8859-1 [22] only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047 [14].

Your best bet is to URL-encode and decode them.

```
response.setHeader("Info", URLEncoder.encode(arabicWord, "UTF-8"));
```

and

```
String arabicWord = URLDecoder.decode(response.getHeader("Info"), "UTF-8");
```

URL-encoding will transform them into [`%nn` format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which is perfectly valid ISO-8859-1. Note that the data sent in the headers may have size limitations. Rather send it in the response body instead, in plain text, JSON, CSV or XML format. Using custom HTTP headers this way is namely a design smell.

Comment: I needed to pass a UTF-8 string from PHP to Javascript via regular HTTP headers and url-encoding helped, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where `word` variable is comming from, but try this:

```
arabicWord = new String(d, "UTF-8");
```

UPDATE: Looks like the problem is with UTF-8 encoded data in HTTP *headers*, see: [HTTP headers encoding/decoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324470) for detailed discussion.