# Safari - Special Char in header

Tags: api, rest, encoding, http-headers

Due to language adaptation I need to place some "special" chars in a custom header (chars like é, á, í, ç, and others)...
On the server side i'm using ASP.NET MVC.
It all works fine on chrome.
But in Safari... I can't figure out witch encoding safari uses...

I tried:

- UTF-8,
- UTF-16,
- ASCII,
- Url Encode,
- a few ISO's

but `alert(headerValue)` always returns crazy chars...

can anyone tell me which encode to use?

Answer (score 0):

There was a specification in the past regarding HTTP header encoding: [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt). But it seems not to be implemented anymore and even removed.

Here are some related links:

- [What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding)
- [HTTP headers encoding/decoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324470/http-headers-encoding-decoding-in-java)
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=601933

In your case, perhaps you could use URL-encoded string for the value of this custom header.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: yeah... url-encoding also didn't work... im starting to assume that safari won't accept any non-regular char... I would love to have an authority answer here... something in the lines of a apple article or something...